# Best way to check for installed yum package/rpm version in Ansible and use it

Tags: ansible

I've been getting my feet wet with Ansible (2.0.0.2) on CentOS 7. I'm trying to obtain a version from an installed rpm/yum package, but ran into a warning message when running the script.

Ansible script:

```
---
- name: Get version of RPM
  shell: yum list installed custom-rpm | grep custom-rpm | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'-' -f1
  register: version
  changed_when: False

- name: Update some file with version
  lineinfile:
    dest: /opt/version.xml
    regexp: "<version>"
    line: "  <version>{{ version.stdout }}</version>"
```

Running this works fine and does what it's supposed to, but it's returning a warning after it executes:

> ok: [default] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "yum list installed custom-rpm | grep custom-rpm | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'-' -f1", "delta": "0:00:00.255406", "end": "2016-05-17 23:11:54.998838", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-05-17 23:11:54.743432", "stderr": "", "stdout": "3.10.2", "stdout_lines": ["3.10.2"], "warnings": ["Consider using yum module rather than running yum"]}
>
> **[WARNING]: Consider using yum module rather than running yum**

I looked up information for the yum module on the [Ansible site](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html), but I don't really want to install/update/delete anything.

I could simply ignore it or suppress it, but I was curious if there was a better way?

Comment: `which yum` didn't work for me, but `warn=no` at the end did. Looks like `shell: yum list installed elasticsearch | grep elasticsearch | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'-' -f1 warn=no` Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it is perfectly fine. The check which is causing the warning is very simply and just checks the first *word* against a pre-defined list. It ignores further options and often results in warnings which can not be solved with the corresponding module, like in the `yum` case.

To get rid of the warning you can simply do a `which`:

```
shell: `which yum` list installed custom-rpm | grep custom-rpm | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'-' -f1
```

`which` looks up the the complete path of `yum`, which then is executed. It's the exact same thing, but from viewpoint of Ansible it calls `which`, not `yum` which avoids the warning.

If you want to deactivate this kind of warnings globally you can set `command_warnings = False` in your `ansible.cfg`. (See [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#command-warnings))

According to the docs you can also add `warn=no` at the end of your command but this really looks strange to me as it appears to be part of the command.

Comment: Is it possible to gather it using facts or something assimilated?

Comment: You can store the output of the task as a var or use local facts by adding a tiny script on the remote host(s) - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d

Comment: Redundant grep + awk pair can be reduced to just `awk '/custom-rpm/{print $2}' `.

Comment: it would be better to use the yum module

Answer (score 23):

I just want to update this old discussion to point out that there is now a package module that makes this more straightforward

```
- name: get the rpm or apt package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: "auto"

- name: show apache2 version
  debug: var=ansible_facts.packages.apache2[0].version
```

Comment: great! just you need to use `ansible_facts.packages['pkg-name']` if the name contains hyphen.

Comment: I think this is the best approach for this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html

Answer (score 10):

I think more native ansible way would be:

```
- name: get package version
  yum:
    list: package_name
  register: package_name_version

- name: set package version
  set_fact:
    package_name_version: "{{ package_name_version.results|selectattr('yumstate','equalto','installed')|map(attribute='version')|list|first }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's okay to suppress this warning in your case. Use `args` like:

```
---
- name: Get version of RPM
  shell: yum list installed custom-rpm | grep custom-rpm | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'-' -f1
  register: version
  changed_when: False
  args:
    warn: no
```

Equivalent to [`warn=no`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) on the `shell:` line but tidier.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like any of these answers.

```
  - name: use command to pull version
    command: '/usr/bin/rpm -qa custom-rpm --queryformat %{VERSION}'
    register: version
    ignore_warnings: True
    changed_when: False
```

Comment: I'd just add, that simple `-q` instead of `-qa` should be sufficient.

Comment: This should be replaced with package_facts in 2.5

Answer (score 3):

How about you use RPM to retrieve the version directly in stead of going trough various pipes:

```
rpm -q --qf "%{VERSION}" custom-rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

use the YUM module as suggested. This really helps. You need not do any installation/update/delete. 
More over this gives you more options like if the package is already installed it would just ignore it.

Comment: But he's NOT installing/upgrading/removing.  He's using Tim to determine the version of "custom-rpn".  I'd think there would be a way to suppress the "Consider using..." warning message somehow for a specific section in the playbook...

Comment: The yum module has a *list* argument that performs a repoquery on the specified package so you can find information about installed packages.

This question is better answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551620/how-to-get-the-installed-yum-packages-with-ansible

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you can use the shell command.
I found this answer useful for using the ansible yum module instead of the shell command as recommended by the ansible warning:
[How can I get the installed YUM packages with Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551620/how-to-get-the-installed-yum-packages-with-ansible)

Summarizing it here for easy reference:
You can use yum list from the native yum module in ansible.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Get installed packages
      sudo: yes
      yum:  list=installed
      register: yum_packages
      changed_when: False
```

To view the contents of yum_packages:

```
    - debug:
        var: yum_packages
```

yum_packages contains a list of all installed packages.

You can then get the version of package of interest by:

```
- debug: var=item
  with_items: "{{yum_packages|json_query(jsonquery)}}"
  vars:
    jsonquery: "results[?name=='tar'].version"
```

Please note that jsonquery is only available from ansible 2.2 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Varaint of peaxol answer setting a fact with the installed package version number for futher tests

```
- name: Find if custom_rpm is installed
  yum:
    list: custom_rpm
  register: custom_rpm_yum_packages
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

- name: Extract custom_rpm actual installed version
  set_fact:
     actual_custom_rpm_version:  "{{custom_rpm_yum_packages|json_query(jsonquery)}}"
  vars:
     jsonquery: "results[?yumstate=='installed'].version"
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

- debug:
    var: actual_custom_rpm_version
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `ignore_errors`
option to handle this.  See the [Error Handing](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html) page for details and examples

Comment: `ignore_errors` would continue execution of the playbook after an error happened. But here we got a warning, so it will proceed anyway. `ignore_errors` will not suppress warnings. (not even error messages)