# How can I get the installed apt packages with Ansible?

Tags: debian, ansible, idempotent

I am trying to list all installed packages on my [Debian 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_7_(Wheezy)) (Wheezy), [8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) (Jessie), and [9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch) machines. There are easy ways dealing with it using [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) or `dpkg`, but I could not find a proper way to do this with Ansible out of the box.

Is there a nice and smooth way to do this?

For [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) machines I found this post: *[How can I get the installed YUM packages with Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551620/how-to-get-the-installed-yum-packages-with-ansible)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like Ansible provides any modules that would support this.  You'll have to use `shell` or `command`.

```
- name: Get packages
  shell: dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W
  register: packages

- name: Print packages
  debug:
    msg: "{{ packages.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: thanks for your idea to use dpkg-query, never thought about that one yet.

Answer (score 8):

Since Ansible 2.5 you can use the package_facts module:
*[ansible.builtin.package_facts module – Package information as facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_facts_module.html)*

```
- name: Gather package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: auto

- name: Debug if package is present
  debug:
    msg: 'yes, mypackage is present'
  when: '"mypackage" in ansible_facts.packages'

- name: Debug if package is absent
  debug:
    msg: 'no, mypackage is absent'
  when: '"mypackage" not in ansible_facts.packages'
```

Mind you, you need the ansible-apt module on Debian for that (which is kindly provided by *[bootstrap](https://galaxy.ansible.com/robertdebock/bootstrap)*).