# No package_facts from Ubuntu 18 server?

Tags: ansible

I though package_facts module seemed useful but on a Ubuntu 18.04 server I get an "unsupported" message, is this a bug?

```
- name: get the rpm or apt package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: "auto"
```

output:

```
{"ansible_facts": {"packages": {}}, "changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported package manager: auto"}
```

If a change to manager "apt" I get:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to use the apt python bindings, please ensure they are installed under the python the module runs under"}
```

Comment: You can't use package_facts in ubuntu - instead try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434449/how-to-get-the-installed-apt-packages-with-ansible

Answer (score 2):

(Ubuntu 18.04, Ansible 2.7.9, Python 2.7.15+)

**Short answer**

Install Ubuntu package `python-apt`

**Details**

The module [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_facts_module.html#package-facts-package-information-as-facts) requires the Python *apt* package.

```
$ grep 'import apt' /home/admin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/package_facts.py
    import apt
```

This Python package is provided by the Ubuntu package `python-apt`

```
$ apt-file list python-apt
python-apt: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't verify because now it seems to be a bug that gives me empty result
(https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55850)