# Ansible yum list installed and available packages

Tags: ansible, yum

I want to get all installed and available packages using Ansible `yum` module. I tried below snippet but it return empty result.

```yaml
- name: print
  yum:
    list: installed,available
  register: pkg
```

Comment: Maybe you can follow this link "[How to get the installed yum packages with ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551620/how-to-get-the-installed-yum-packages-with-ansible)"

Comment: I am able to get the list if i use either installed or available. My requirement is I should be able to use both option together :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`list` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameter-list) is a string, not a list, as pointed by the documentation, so, if you pass something else than the reserved words — `installed`, `updates`, `available` or `repos` — it will be considered as a packaged and will probably return your nothing.

We can also confirm this by Ansible code source, where the `list` value is considered in an `if .. elif .. else`:

```py
if stuff == 'installed':
    return [ pkg_to_dict(p) for p in sorted(is_installed(module, repoq, '-a', conf_file, qf=is_installed_qf)) if p.strip() ]
elif stuff == 'updates':
    return [ pkg_to_dict(p) for p in sorted(is_update(module, repoq, '-a', conf_file, qf=qf)) if p.strip() ]
elif stuff == 'available':
    return [ pkg_to_dict(p) for p in sorted(is_available(module, repoq, '-a', conf_file, qf=qf)) if p.strip() ]
elif stuff == 'repos':
    return [ dict(repoid=name, state='enabled') for name in sorted(repolist(module, repoq)) if name.strip() ]
else:
    return [ pkg_to_dict(p) for p in sorted(is_installed(module, repoq, stuff, conf_file, qf=is_installed_qf) + is_available(module, repoq, stuff, conf_file, qf=qf)) if p.strip() ]
```

*<sup>Source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/00911a75ad6635834b6d28eef41f197b2f73c381/packaging/os/yum.py#L582</sup>*

You should be able to make a combined list of all of them using list concatenation and two `yum` tasks:

```yaml
- yum:
    list: installed
  register: installed_pkg

- yum:
    list: available
  register: available_pkg

- debug:
    var: installed_pkg.results + available_pkg
```