# How to grep/parse in string with Ansible

Tags: parsing, ansible, grep

I have problem with ansible. I need get version of apache with ansible, and I'm using command "httpd -v" in /bin/ folder of apache.
Now, I've got output looks like "Server version: Apache/2.4.48 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VS16 Server built:   May 18 2021 10:45:56".
So, can you help me please? I tried to use "regex" and  there was still error.

Comment: Is a [way to check for installed yum package/rpm version in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096739/6771046) helpful for you?

Comment: No, because it is project for windows PC's.
But I thank you

Answer (score 1):

Register the result of the command

```yaml
    - command: httpd -v
      register: result
```

gives, for example,

```yaml
result.stdout: |-
  Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (FreeBSD)
  Server built:   unknown
```

This is actually a YAML dictionary. Let's keep it in a variable. For example,

```yaml
apache: "{{ result.stdout|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
apache:
  Server built: unknown
  Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (FreeBSD)
```

Now, you can reference the attributes. For example,

```yaml
apache['Server version']: Apache/2.4.46 (FreeBSD)
```

and split the version

```yaml
apache_version: "{{ apache['Server version']|split(' ')|first|
                                             split('/')|last }}"
```

gives

```yaml
apache_version: 2.4.46
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: srv
  vars:
    apache: "{{ result.stdout|from_yaml }}"
    apache_version: "{{ apache['Server version']|split(' ')|first|
                                                 split('/')|last }}"
  tasks:
    - command: httpd -v
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: apache_version
```

Comment: I have this code, but it isn't working? Do you help me, please?

Screenshot of my code: https://ctrlv.cz/Q2MK

Answer (score 0):

using `regex_search`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Run httpd command
    shell: httpd -v
    register: httpd_version

  - name: show the extracted output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ httpd_version.stdout |regex_search('Server version.*?/([^ ]+).*','\\1') }}"
```